# How can I loop audio a custom number of times in a queue with just_audio in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio, just-audio, audio-service

How to loop audio in a queue for a custom duration (e.g. N number of loops), then move to the next item in the queue which would also play on loop for N number of times.

For example, loop a short audio clip, of say 5 seconds length, for 15 seconds total (3 loops); then after move to the second item in the queue, say an audio clip of 30 seconds, which would loop for say 60 seconds (2 loops).

In my example code, I am using [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) with [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) to play the actual audio. I am setting the audio player to LoopMode.one (which loops indefinitely, as I am not sure how to set this to loop only N number of times).

```
class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler {

  @override
  Future<void> play() async {
     setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode.one);
    _audioPlayer.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
    _audioPlayer.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItems(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) async {
    final audioSource = mediaItems.map(_createAudioSource);
    _playlist.addAll(audioSource.toList());
    final newQueue = queue.value..addAll(mediaItems);
    queue.add(newQueue);
    await _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(_playlist);
    setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode.one);
  }

  UriAudioSource _createAudioSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    return AudioSource.asset(
     mediaItem.id,
      tag: mediaItem,
    );
  }

/// More code
}
```

And when I add an item to my queue, I set a custom duration to MediaItem (which is ignored).

```
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    List<MediaItem> mediaItems = [
                      const MediaItem(
                        id: 'assets/audio/jingle.mp3',
                        title: 'jingle',
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 15)
                      ),
                      const MediaItem(
                        id: 'assets/audio/jazz.mp3',
                        title: 'jazz',
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 30)
                      ),
                    ];
                    getIt<AudioHandler>().addQueueItems(mediaItems);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Add to queue'),
                ),
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to split this into two separate questions. The first is how to achieve the looping affect in just_audio and move to the next item after 15 seconds. After you get an answer to that, if you then have a question about how to implement audio_service over the top of that, you could ask that separately. Please also mention whether 15 seconds is an exact multiple of your audio asset duration, or whether you expect it to chop of the current iteration of the loop at 15 seconds even if it's only halfway through playing that iteration.

Comment: Good advice @Ryan Heise, I have simplified the question, hopefully it is now clearer.

Comment: I'll write up an answer for the just_audio part. Your question still seems tied to audio_service, but as discussed I'll focus on the just_audio part.

Comment: Perfect solutions, thanks for the answer! I also made my title clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer focuses on how to loop and sequence in just_audio.

The following code prepares a playlist that will play `jingle.mp3` 3 times and then play `jazz.mp3` 2 times:

```dart
_playlist.addAll([
  LoopingAudioSource(count: 3, child: AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jingle.mp3')),
  LoopingAudioSource(count: 2, child: AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jazz.mp3')),
]);
```

Since the looping is built into the specification of the playlist, you should not set any loop mode on the player. Let the playlist play normally according to its specification.

Another way to achieve the same effect is to just insert multiple copies of the same audio source into the playlist:

```dart
_playlist.addAll([
  AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jingle.mp3'),
  AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jingle.mp3'),
  AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jingle.mp3'),
  AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jazz.mp3'),
  AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jazz.mp3'),
]);
```

Or with collection loops:

```dart
_playlist.addAll([
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jingle.mp3'),
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) AudioSource.asset('assets/audio/jazz.mp3'),
]);
```